# EF CORE - Fluent API - cascading delete restrict to on table

Tags: c#, .net-core, ef-fluent-api, ef-core-2.0

**The model:**

```
public class AccountUser
{
    public long AccountUserId { get; set; }
    ...
    public long UserPermissionGroupId { get; set; }
    public UserPermissionGroup UserPermissionGroup { get; set; }
}

public class UserPermissionGroup
{
    public long UserPermissionGroupId { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

**The question:**
How do I set foreign key on table AccountUser->UserPermissionGroup to restrict on delete?

I'm unable to find example how to set foreign key on delete action to restrict to  only one table. I can not use something like WithMany/WithOne and then OnDelete as in this example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships#cascade-delete-1 because I have no reference from UserPermissionGroup back to AccountUser.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In your fluent API you can do something like this:

```
builder.Entity<AccountUser>()
    .HasOne(a => a.UserPermissionGroup)
    .WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict);
```